# Convert string syminfo.ticker to variable

Tags: pine-script, stock, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to make a **ratio conversion (for ADR)** using the subjacent data. I need to convert the ticker info that i get with `syminfo.ticker` in a variable that a can use in a simple math formula.

I load a data base with all ratios declare in individual variables

```
GOOGL = 58
// (...)
MELI = 60
// (...)
// etc.

ggalc = request.security('BCBA:GGAL', '1D', close)
ggals = request.security('NASDAQ:GGAL', '1D', close)

ccl = ggalc * 10 / ggals
stock = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, close)
stock_simb = syminfo.ticker

CEDEAR = ccl * stock / stock_simb

plot(CEDEAR)
```

For example, if I'm watching the MELI stock, the `stock_simb` is "MELI" as a string, but i can't figure out a way to convert that in the variable value to use for the `CEDEAR` calculus.

Comment: What exactly do you expect from syminfo.ticker? You've done a great job requesting security data above. Do you expect a close value as well that you could/should request like the others?

Answer (score 0):

Well i took another approach, i just used two arrays storing the tickers and ratios and with a for loop it identifies the position and voilà.

```
tickers = array.from("GOOGL","MELI")
ratios = array. From(58,60)
var int pos = na

for i = 0 to array.size(tickers)
    comp = array.get(tickers, i)
    if comp == syminfo.ticker
        pos := i
        break

ggalc = request.security('BCBA:GGAL', '1D', close)
ggals = request.security('NASDAQ:GGAL', '1D', close)

ccl = ggalc * 10 / ggals
stock = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, close)
stock_simb_ratio = array.get(ratios, pos)

CEDEAR = ccl * stock / stock_simb_ratio

plot(CEDEAR,"Precio del CEDEAR",linewidth = 2, trackprice = true, color=color.white)
```